# DataTables - Sorting not working after content update

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using DataTables (version 1.10.18) and I'm updating rows and its content via jQuery.

My table is initalized with this code:

```
$(".summary").append(tableContent);
var otable = $('.summary').DataTable({
initComplete: function () {
this.api().columns([0, 1, 2, 3]).every(function () {
var column = this;
var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
  .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
  .on('change', function () {
    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
    $(this).val()
   );
column
.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
.draw();
});
column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
});
});
},
 "pageLength": records_per_page,
 "language": {
 "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Italian.json"
 },
 "order": [[0, 'desc']],
 "ordering": true,
 "scrollX": true,
 "scrollY":"50vh",
 "searching":false,
 "info":false,
 "paging": false
 });
```

Then I've an input field that searches in a SharePoint list (via Rest API). So I make an AJAX call, I get the response from SharePoint web service and I prepare HTML code with new data (some data returned from web services needs to be modified). Finally I update the table content using this code:

```
var otable = $('.summary).DataTable();
otable.clear().draw();
$(".dataTables_scrollBody>.summary").append(newContent);
otable.rows().invalidate().draw();
```

`newContent` is something like:

```
newContent = "<tbody><tr><td>content</td><td>content</td></tr></tbody>";
```

Content is updating correctly and sorting arrows are visible in the table header, they are also changing their own active status (desc or asc) but content is not sorted.

I've tried a lot of solutions found online but no one is working for me. In the content update section I'm also adding rows using `.append()` method.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Answers will just be random stabs in the dark unless you can provide enough info for us to be able reproduce the behavior.

Comment: @TravisActon question updated with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest, instead of appending the row, you should use the https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add() add method which is exposed by datatable api. This will automatically apply all the initial settings to new added row.

Comment: Is it possible to use row.add() with HTML code that I've already prepared? I mean doing something like table.row.add("<tr><td>content</td><td>content</td></tr>").draw());

Comment: i don't think the way you have shown is possible. your content should be an array where each index will represent respective column. lets say you have 4 column then your row add function should be table.row.add( [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ).draw();

Comment: if you think using add in your case is more overhead then you can reinitialize the table again after you add the row in your original code. after you write your append just add $('.summary').DataTable() it should work.

Comment: I’ve tried to reinitialize DataTable after append but sorting is not working. No errors, content is correctly showed but sorting still not working.

Comment: one last thing i can suggest is to redraw the table after you append the rows $('.summary').DataTable().draw() . if this doesn't work then unfortunately you will have to use add function

Comment: I confirm that I solved with row.add() method. It seems the only way in my case. Thank you Sachin.